# Connect to Database on Server using Python without putting Database password

Tags: php, python, mysql, database, api

I have a situation as Follows..
I am writing a python program.which asks users to enter username and password to begin with.Now I grab user name and password  from database  stored Online on web server Hoisted by GoDady and compare it with user entered Credentials .

Approach I used to do so is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    
                     user="john",         
                     passwd="megajonhy", 
                     db="jonhydb")       

cur = db.cursor()    

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")  

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]

db.close()
```

so as seen connection is made to database inside the program.for which i have to provide username and password of database inside the program.this method is not good if I want to give away my program to other.Because then I would like my users to input user Id and Password. and instead of connecting to database inside the program I want program to call a web-script which does it all for me and return if user is Authenticated user or not.

what is the best approach to my scenario?

Languages Used: Desktop Program (Python) : web(PHP) :Database(MYSQL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables for this case.

You have to first `export` your variable and then access in the same script as:

```
import os
password = os.environ['Your-password-variable']
```

This might help: https://godjango.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Use a config file.

```
{
    "db_user": "john",
    "db_host": "localhost",
    "db_pass": "megajonhy",
    "database" : "jonhydb"
}
```

Then load it in

```
import json
import MySQLdb

#Read setting and make available in settings dict
with open('/path/to/conf.json') as data_file:    
    settings = json.load(data_file)

#Open database connection(HOST, USER, PASS, DB)
db = MySQLdb.connect(settings["db_host"],
                 settings["db_user"],
                 settings["db_pass"],
                 settings["database"])
```